# React Native - Native audio player on locked device screen

Tags: react-native

I'm using **react-native-sound** library for audio files to play inside Rn app for both iOS and Android.
I have question about locked screen, I would like to have audio player on locked screen.
Currently behaviour is different, on iOS audio stops after lock, on Android it continues.
I would like something like this:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately no, you would have to change native code.

Comment: Did you by chance try?: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-music-control

Comment: react native music control shows controls on lockscreen ios for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but I just installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-music-control and using it alongside react native sound and everything works for the lock screen in ios. The audio continues to play in background when using the react native sound option:

```
// Enable playback in silence mode
Sound.setCategory('Playback');
```

If you follow the docs for both libraries it should work for ios. In the react native music control library, make sure you follow the part about setting the Background Mode in xcode. Bare in mind that in the simulator the lock screen was not showing, only when the app is on the device does it show but the audio does play in background on simulator.